# Compare each element in a list with a column of lists in a dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list such as

```
[ apple, orange, banana ]
```

that I want to match with lists in a dataframe column and create a new column with the matched list of elements

| fruits | match |
| --- | --- |
| [apple, banana, berry ] | [apple, banana] |
| [orange] | [orange] |

How can I accomplish this in an efficient way? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have a working example, I considered that your data were lists of strings :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'fruits':[['apple','orange','berry'],['orange']]
})

ml = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
```

Then I created a function that return the list of matching elements, or 0 if there's no match :

```
def matchFruits(row):
    result = []
    for fruit in row['fruits']:
        if fruit in ml :
            result.append(fruit)

    return result if len(result) > 0 else 0
```

> `result = [fruit for fruit in row['fruits'] if fruit in ml]` for list comprehesion aficionados.

Finally, I called this function on the whole DataFrame with `axis = 1` to add a new column to the initial DataFrame :

```
df["match"] = df.apply(matchFruits, axis = 1)
```

The output is the following, it is different from your example since your result was 0 even though 'orange' was in both list. If it is not the requested behavior, please edit your question.

```
                   fruits            match
0  [apple, orange, berry]  [apple, orange]
1                [orange]         [orange]
```

Comment: Convert the list to `set` to avoid quadratic complexity in the loop

Comment: @mozway how would that work ? can you give a quick example ? I mean, which list should be converted ?

Comment: `ml` should be a set

Answer (score 1):

You can try `apply` a `filter`

```py
lst = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']

df['match'] = df['fruits'].apply(lambda ls: list(filter(lambda x: x in lst, ls)))
```

```
print(df)

                   fruits            match
0  [apple, orange, berry]  [apple, orange]
1                [orange]         [orange]
``
```